# How to install requests module in python 3.4 version on windows?

Tags: pip, python-3.4

What command should I use in command prompt to install requests module in python 3.4 version ???

> pip install requests

is not useful to install requests module in python 3.4 version. Because while running the script below error is coming

ImportError : no module named 'requests'

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`python -m pip install requests` or `py -m pip install requests`

Comment: You might have to run your shell in Administrator mode by right-clicking on e.g. PowerShell and choose Run as Administrator

Comment: working fine with windows 10 - 64 bits. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I found navigating to my Python folder via CMD worked

`cd C:\Python36\`

and then running the commandline:

`python -m pip install requests`

Comment: I'm getting error as 'python' is not recognized as internal or external command.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, use this:

```
py -m install requests
```

Comment: Sorry guys, it has to be: py -m pip install requests

Comment: you should edit your answer if it is incorrect. The 'edit' button is under your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you hace problems with the python command only need add the route C:/python34 or the route went you have python installed:

1. List item
2. Right click on "My computer"
3. Click "Properties"
4. Click "Advanced system settings" in the side panel
5. Click "Environment Variables"
6. Click the "New" below system variables
7. find the path variable and edit
8. add this variable ;C:\Python34 with the semicolon

now you can run this comand

`cd C:\Python34`

`python -m pip install requests`

Answer (score 1):

I install it by Anaconda:

```
pip install requests
```

and there is no error occured like you.

Answer (score 0):

After installing python which comes with  pip run and exe and input "pip install requests"
It should do