# Error installing any python package using pip

Tags: python, windows

So I am trying to install the python package http_client or httplib on Windows 10 using Python3.7.3. But when I try to do this it returns an error that sort of tells me that libcurl is not installed.

I have googled the question and it the community just seems to say "install libcurl". Not helpful.

The error shows as follows:

```
cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fo_wbpht\pycurl\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am expecting it to just say "successfully installed" but instead get this error which I can't fix. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Why is "install libcurl" not helpful advice? You can download from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html and then specify curl_dir as the installation path as described in the error message?

Comment: It was not helpful because it did not work. I went through those steps, tried again and it still does not work :/

Comment: Can you try running `pip install pycurl --curl-dir=/your/install/path/libcurl` first? (instead of `pip install httplib`) If that doesn't work, what error does it give?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this was to do with my permission settings set by my company. Issue resolved by white-listing the file for python.

Answer (score -1):

[import httplib ImportError: No module named httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778252/import-httplib-importerror-no-module-named-httplib)

> You are running Python 2 code on Python 3. In Python 3, the module has
>   been renamed to `http.client`.

Also, try looking for packages that have Windows support and follow their installation steps for Windows.

Look at possibly easier modules to install:

[How to install requests module in python 3.4 version on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536946/how-to-install-requests-module-in-python-3-4-version-on-windows)

Comment: The issue is not to do with requests as that package downloaded and installed fine. But then I was trying to install http.client and that still does not work with the exact same error :/